# Where does the local static variable inside static member function resides in memory?

Tags: c++, static-methods, static-variables

Where does the local static variable inside static member function resides in memory? 
For example :

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static void Bar()
    {
         static int fooBar;
    }
};
```

Where does 'fooBar' resides in memory and when it was allocated.

Comment: Like all variables, it resides in memory wherever the compiler chooses to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is obviously compiler and platform specific but generally, on PC, it resides in same memory as global variables. It gets initialized on first entry to the function.

Comment: It's 'allocated' on program start up. The rules are exactly the same as for a static variable inside any other kind of function

Comment: @john - That's not precisely true.   It's not required to exist before the function it contains is called for the first time.   But, when the function is called for the first time, it is required to exist.  So an implementation CAN allocate it at program startup, but is not required to

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the clarification. I was trying to answer in the context of the reply above 'on PC'.

Comment: @Peter, c++ standard says [The storage for these entities lasts for the duration of the program](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.static), which implies even if the function is not call, memory for the static variable does exist for the duration of the program.

Comment: @SPD - You can't just cherry pick a single clause from the standard (or in your case, an unofficial draft).   In any event, in the draft you link to,  https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl#4  says differently.

Comment: @Peter There's no conflict here: the link you provided is about dynamic initialization of static variable, we're talking about memory storage. (Regarding cpp draft -- if you could find an official cpp standard freely available online, please share the link and I'd love to use that)

Comment: I wound up here because I realized that function-local static variables don't allocate, allowing a function containing one to be `noexcept`. Since there are finitely many functions there must be finitely many function-local statics, so I guess that memory can be allocated up front. But that can't be a stack because construction can fail, so if you start constructing `a` then start constructing `b` then `a` fails, you'd have a gap in the stack. Maybe it's an (atomic) stack of pointers but the objects live at predefined locations? Anyone know how this bookkeeping works?